# How do I display things only once in a cshtml file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

i am doing an ASP.NET project and i never worked with this before, i am having a problem in a cshtml file, first of all i know that i have a foreach and the values will appear more than once, but the code doesnt work if I put the @Html.LabelFor and @Html.DisplayNameFor outside the foreach and create another variable, i want to display that only once and i have no idea how to do it

```
@foreach (var pap in Model.PessoasEpisodios)
{

    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.LabelFor(a => pap.Episodios.Temporadas.Series.Nome, "Nome Série")

        </th>
        <th>

            @Html.LabelFor(a => pap.Episodios.Temporadas.Nome, "Nome Temporada")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(a => pap.Episodios.Nome)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(a => pap.Papel)
        </th>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(a => pap.Episodios.Temporadas.Series.Nome)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(a => pap.Episodios.Temporadas.Nome)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(a => pap.Episodios.Nome)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(a => pap.Papel)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Please be specific about what you tried and what error you got.

Comment: Sorry, but i am new arround here and i wasnt so specific when i declare the variable i need to specify the same thing that i specify in the foreach? i mean this : "in Model.PessoasEpisodios" ?

Comment: in  this case you need 2 modal in one modal where modal contains your display name and list also so you can display like this
@html.displayfor( m => m.propertyname)
@forreach() { }

Comment: so you can place @html.display outside loop and it will display only once

Answer (score 0):

`Model.PessoasEpisodios` links to a list or enumerable in your case, which does not store the attributes you want to access. This means that the attributes that you want to access do exists in the items it holds. So in order to access it, you could get the first index of your list, and display its attributes (all your list iterations have these, but assuming you have items in your list, this is probably the safest).

And as far as I'm aware, this is the only way.

```
<th>
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(a => pap.Episodios[0].Nome)
</th>
```

EDIT:
You could also use `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` in this case, instead of [0]. It's basically close to the same thing.

Comment: Before accessing an episode via index, you should check to make sure an object exists that index so that you don't get a NullReferenceException.

Comment: Hence the assuming you have an item in your list point. I personally check this beforehand and proceed to not display the table a all, but this is fully your own preference.